# Multiple textbox search using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in **MySQL** with 5 data fields: `id`, `name`, `total marks`, `percentage`, and `rank`. I already fetch and displayed all data, but I want search and display by 3 fields name: `total marks`, and `rank`. These 3 will be entered in text boxes.
Please mention the particular query for this 3 fields search.

Comment: Just use WHERE clause. Did you take some time to ready MySQL manual?

Answer (score 1):

As you've had to ask this question, I'd like to first of all point you towards the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/) and the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php). However, I'll also give you some pointers.

First of all, you'll need to post these search values to your PHP code. This can be done using a form.

```
<form method="POST" action="script.php">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="total_marks" type="text" />
    <input name="rank" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Then, you'll need to access these values in your PHP script as such.

```
// script.php
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$total_marks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total_marks']);
$rank = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rank']);
// I'll leave SQL injection protection up to you
```

Finally, you'll need to pass these queries to an SQL query to retrieve the items from your database. As you haven't posted your exact scheme, you'll have to modify this to suit your needs. Also, I've left the actual database loading/access to you.

```
// script.php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (
    `name` = '{$name}' AND
    `total_marks` = '{$total_marks}' AND
    `rank` = '{$rank}'
)";
```

Rather than passing the variables directly to the SQL query and using `mysql_real_escape_string` or similar functions, I'd look in to using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for security and for some database abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly

```
Select * 
FROM Keys
WHERE name = 'stringName' AND total_marks = numberTotalMarks AND rank = procent
```